# Alfresco Solr SearchService.query() error parsing Xpath

Tags: xpath, solr, alfresco

I'm trying to query for some files in Alfresco using SearchService; my idea is:

1) **get folder's noderef** where I want to search in for files

2) then **get noderef's path** via NodeService

3) finally **query Solar via SearchService** to find files in that specific path

The problem raises when querying to Solr, I get the following exception:

```
    ERROR [solr.core.SolrCore] [http-bio-8443-exec-1] org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: **Cannot parse** 'PATH:"/{http\://www.alfresco.org/model/application/1.0}company_home/{http\://www.alfresco.org/model/application/1.0}user_homes/{http\://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}abeecher/{http\://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}nominas//*"': **Failed to parse XPath**...
Unexpected '{http://www.alfresco.org/model/application/1.0}company_home/{http://www.alfresco.org/model/application/1.0}user_homes/{http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}abeecher/{http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}nominas//*'
```

If I replace the full prefixes by prefixes of type cm: etc... the query works well.

**Is there any "Alfresco Way" to do this instead of transforming the string with a regex? Or am I doing something wrong?**

Code I'm using is:

```
Path path3 = nodeService.getPath(folder); 

    SearchParameters sp = new SearchParameters();
    sp.addStore(Repository.getStoreRef());
    sp.setLanguage(SearchService.LANGUAGE_LUCENE);
    sp.setQuery("PATH:\"/{http://www.alfresco.org/model/application/1.0}company_home/{http://www.alfresco.org/model/application/1.0}user_homes/{http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}abeecher/{http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}nominas//*\"");    
    //sp.setQuery(path3);                           
    //sp.setQuery(path3.toString());                           
    ResultSet results = null;
    results = searchService.query(sp);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

afaik PATH-Queries using full namespace syntax is not supported. Take a look here: http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Search#Path_Queries

You'll have to use the prefix version. But, please don't use a regex to get the prefix. There is an `org.alfresco.service.namespace.NamespacePrefixResolver` (bean NamespaceService) taht defines a method `Collection<String> getPrefixes(String namespaceURI)`.

your dummy code to get the QNamePath of a node:

```
Path path = nodeService.getPath(folder);
final Map<String, String> cache = new HashMap<String, String>();
final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(128);
for (final Path.Element e : path)
{
    if (e instanceof Path.ChildAssocElement)
    {
        final QName qname = ((Path.ChildAssocElement)e).getRef().getQName();
        if (qname != null)
        {
            String prefix = cache.get(qname.getNamespaceURI());
            if (prefix == null)
            {
                // first request for this namespace prefix, get and cache result
                Collection<String> prefixes = ns.getPrefixes(qname.getNamespaceURI());
                prefix = prefixes.size() != 0 ? prefixes.iterator().next() : "";
                cache.put(qname.getNamespaceURI(), prefix);
            }
            buf.append('/').append(prefix).append(':').append(ISO9075.encode(qname.getLocalName()));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        buf.append('/').append(e.toString());
    }
}
String searchPath = buf.toString();
```